# Proof check: Interchanging integration and expectation using Tonelli's theorem?

Tags: probability, integration, proof-verification, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process. I am wondering whether or not the following holds, as a consequence of Tonelli's theorem:

$$ E[\int_0^T X_t^2 ds] = \int_0^T E[X_t^2] ds$$

My attempt:

$$ E[\int_0^T X_t^2 dt] = \int_X \int_0^T X_t^2 dt f(x) dx$$

Since $X_t^2$ and $f(x)$ are non-negative, we rearrange to obtain

$$ E[\int_0^T X_t^2 dt] = \int_0^T \int_X X_t^s f(x) dx dt$$

And hence

$$ E[\int_0^T X_t^2 dt] = \int_0^T E[X_t^2] dt$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is indeed correct because both expectation and integration are linear operators...(of course if both converge)

Comment: Uhm, $\int_0^T X_t^2\mathsf d s = X_t^2 \int_0^T\mathsf d s = X_t^2 T$  Are you sure you are integrating with respect to the correct variable (because $s$ does not appear inside the integral)?   Also: Is $T$ a random variable or a constant?

Comment: That was a typo sorry

Comment: Since the question involves Tonelli's Theorem of measure theory it is necessary to state the hypothesis properly. First thing to note is that not every random variable has a density. Secondly, as pointed out by David Ullrich the process $\{X_t\}$ has to be a measurable process if we want to apply Tonelli's Theorem. Under this condition you can interchange expectation and integral even if there is no density. Note that the process may be defined on an abstract space and f(x) does n ot even make sense in general.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @KaviRamaMurthy , do you know (off the top of your head) any authors/books on this general topic? If not I will try and find some myself. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *if* the function $(\omega,t)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is jointly meaurable on $\Omega\times[0,T]$. (I have no idea whether that's clear from the definitions).